# Array named `name` printing character by line rather than word. using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I an trying to console-log an array named **`name`** in JavaScript but its not working as expected. Version i am trying in **`chrome 29`** but no problem with `firefox` is there an restricting to use it.

Printing an array named **`name`** using for loop:

```
var name = ["Hello", "foo", "test", "tried"];

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

    console.log(name[i]);

}
```

**Result:** 
[image]

Printing an array named **`test`** using for loop:

```
var test = ["Hello", "foo", "test", "tried"];

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

    console.log(test[i]);

}
```

**Result:** 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name` is a shorthand for `window.name`, which is a property that contains the name of the current window. The following:

```
var name = ["Hello", "foo", "test", "tried"];
```

doesn't create a new variable. Instead, the array is flattened into a string and the result is assigned to the `name` property:

```
> var name = ["Hello", "foo", "test", "tried"];
undefined
> name
"Hello,foo,test,tried"
```

This is what causes the strange iteration behaviour.

Comment: But it's only happening in chrome. @npe